# Proguard android can't find referenced class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, proguard, inner-classes

in my activity I had some inline AsyncTask that didn't work well on android 11+ so I decided to change all inline code to inner classes.
After change all inline AsyncTask to inner classes I got this warning in proguard and I can't compile the project. In debug mode all work well.

This is my proguard blocking warnings:

```
[proguard] Warning: com.test.MyActivity: can't find referenced class com.test.MyActivity$1
[proguard] Warning: com.test.MyActivity$MyBroadcastReceiver: can't find referenced class com.test.MyActivity$1
[proguard] Warning: com.test.MyActivity$MyBroadcastReceiver: can't find referenced class com.test.MyActivity$1
[proguard] Warning: com.test.MyActivity$MyBroadcastReceiver: can't find referenced class com.test.MyActivity$1
[proguard] Warning: com.test.MyActivity$LoadingTask: can't find referenced class com.test.MyActivity$1
[proguard] Warning: com.test.MyActivity$LoadingTask: can't find referenced class com.test.MyActivity$1
[proguard] Warning: com.test.MyActivity$LoadingTask: can't find referenced class com.test.MyActivity$1
```

This is my actual activity code:

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private final WakefulBroadcastReceiver messageReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final LoadingTask task = new LoadingTask();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        } else {
            task.execute();
        }
    }

    private final class MyBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (context == getContext()) {
                GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
                setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
            } else {
                setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
            }
        }
    }

    private final class LoadingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Long, Boolean> {

        private static final int MAX_SHOW_TIME = 120000;
        private long startTime;
        private LoadingDialog loadingDialog;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            loadingDialog = new LoadingDialog(getContext());
            loadingDialog.show();
        }

        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            synchronized (this) {
                long actualTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                while (!initialize) {
                    publishProgress((actualTime - startTime) / 1000);
                    try {
                        this.wait(250);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
                    actualTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                    if (actualTime - startTime > MAX_SHOW_TIME) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... values) {
            loadingDialog.setProgressValue(values[0]);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            loadingDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Default proguard configuration: ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
Custom proguard configuration (proguard.txt)

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keep class android.** { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers interface * extends com.facebook.model.GraphObject { *; }

-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

# Keep SafeParcelable value, needed for reflection. This is required to support backwards
# compatibility of some classes.
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

# Keep the names of classes/members we need for client functionality.
-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

# Needed for Parcelable/SafeParcelable Creators to not get stripped
-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}

-keep class com.google.** { *; }

-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-keepnames class com.test.client.** implements java.io.Serializable
-keepclassmembernames class com.test.client.** implements java.io.Serializable {
    private !static <fields>;
 }
```

Can anybody help or suggest me the solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem, and changing the scope of the `AsyncTask` worked. You can try with `protected`:

```
...
protected final class LoadingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Long, Boolean> {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `proguard-project.txt` file, you may need to add these lines:

```
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
```

Also, if you extends `Application` or `Service`, you'll need these directives, too:

```
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
```

Comment: my proguard-project.txt already contains this lines, but it doesn't work

Comment: Post the content of your `proguard-project.txt` so I can see what you're doing.

Comment: I posted the proguard configuration

Comment: You posted the default proguard file, not the `proguard-project.txt` within your project, which I ask. Also, `-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }` directive, etc, that is specific to your project should be set in your project's `proguard-project.txt`. Leave the default `proguard-android.txt`, or the `proguard-android-optimize.txt` alone.

Comment: I said that I use default proguard. But the code that I posted is specific for my app. I try to explain better: I have 4 libraries each one with his proguard configuration, the configuration that I posted is the sum of libraries configuration. The code posted is not the default configuration (some code is similar to google play service configuration)

Comment: Okay, then where are the directives `-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity` and `-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver`. You mentioned in your first comment above that you have included them, but I don't see them in your edit?! FYI: Including project's specific ProGuard's directives in the default configuration is bad practice. You should read this [link](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/) about ProGuard for how to do it properly.

Comment: I have already tryed you code but I have the same problem. I know that the default configuration should not be touched, so I didn't change it. The problem verify after convert inline AsyncTask to inner classes, if i convert again the code without changing the proguard configuration, the project compile successfully, so I think the problem is related to private inner classes.

Comment: Maybe try `-keep public class * extends android.os.AsyncTask`. Also, may I ask why you need inner classes? Wouldn't it be better to separate them into external classes and call them internally in your Activity, etc, for example `new MyAsyncTask().execute();`.

Comment: I need to separate code for HoneyComb+ as you can see in onCreate method. Because on some devices with android 4.0.4 with specific settings it's the only way to make it works (I tested seems to be a bug)

Comment: I resolved without editing proguard configuration but changing the `private` keyword to `public`:
`public final class MyBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver`

`public final class LoadingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Long, Boolean>`

This seems to be another bug, this time of proguard

Comment: Yes, you can still have HoneyComb checks, or whatever else, and have AsyncTask in a separate class, and calls it in yours `MyActivity` class. Maybe you need to read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for a proper implementation of AsyncTask. Declaring it `public` only solve _your_ current problem but you will run into other problems in the future. Anyway, good luck!

Comment: In fact I will try to find a solution to make it private. But if you compare my posted code with google docs you will see no differences.

Answer (score 0):

These warnings are printed after the input has been read and before any processing, so -keep options are still irrelevant.

The warnings explain that the compiled com/test/MyActivity.class refers to an anonymous inner class com/test/MyActivity$1.class, but that the anonymous inner class can't be found. This suggests that the code hasn't been recompiled properly. Looking at the source code, I don't see an anonymous inner class right away, so either the activity class hasn't been recompiled, or an old copy of it is lingering in some directory and ends up being read as input. You should start from a clean project, without any old .class files anywhere, and build again.